# Is it possible to get the history of tracks played by XnaMediaPlayer on WP 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using XnaMediaPlayer to play the local device media (XnaMediaPlayer.Play()). Is there a way in which i can get access to the recently played tracks from XnaMediaPlayer?

I don't want to serialize the played track details if I could access it anyway from XnaMediaPlayer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean; you can add items to the history with the [MediaHistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.mediahistory%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) class and even get the current playing item, but I don't think you can get the previous items played...